# Styled-jsx styling not applied to Framer-Motion element

Tags: reactjs, next.js, framer-motion, styled-jsx

I think I'm loosing my mind.

I created a new Nextjs project, installed Framer-Motion via NPM, ran the project in dev mode. Everything compiles and the page loads, but as soon as I add motion to an element, it vanishes with no errors.

I'm getting this both on PC and Mac. I even deleted my node modules and package.lock files and rolled back to a version of Next.js & framer-motion that I've had working in the past but it didn't do the trick. Just for kicks I created a new react app with framer-motion and it worked without issue there.

```js
import {motion} from 'framer-motion';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <motion.div
        className="test"
        animate={{ scale: 1.5 }}
      />
      <style jsx>{`
        .test {
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;
          background-color: red;
        }
      `}</style>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your `styled-jsx` styles are not being applied to the `framer-motion` element.

To style a third-party component like the `motion.div` element you'll need to use the [`resolve` tag from `styled-jsx/css`](https://github.com/vercel/styled-jsx#the-resolve-tag).

```js
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import css from 'styled-jsx/css';

const { className, styles } = css.resolve`
  div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
  }
`;

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <>
            <motion.div
                className={className}
                animate={{ scale: 1.5 }}
            />
            {styles}
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks Julio! That worked, though I have no idea why it worked previously then, but oh well! It might just be worth setting up styled-components for my projects in the future.

Comment: ** EDIT ** I just realized on my last project I used Tailwind, so that explains it. THANKS AGAIN!

Answer (score 1):

I find this `css.resolve` thing extremelly cumbersome to apply afterwards.
Here's another way that works most of the time.
The caveat is that it will get applied to all child components with the same `.test` class. (Just add another parent when necessary)

```
import {motion} from 'framer-motion';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="test-parent">
      <motion.div
        className="test"
        animate={{ scale: 1.5 }}
      />
      <style jsx>{`
        .test-parent :global(.test) {
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;
          background-color: red;
        }
      `}</style>
    </div>
  )
}
```